# Ending while loops in one method from another method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm working on a simple text-based dungeon game in Ruby, and I've run into a snag. Basically, I have one room with a locked door. The key is found in another room and I want the door to be unlocked once the key has been found.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def chest_room
  puts "You are in a small, round room."
  puts "On the floor in front of you is a small wooden chest."
  puts "It does not appear to be locked."
  puts "What do you do?"
  chest_open = false

  while true
  prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
  if next_move == "open chest"
    chest_open = true
    puts "Inside the chest, you see a small, brass key."
    puts "What do you do?"
    prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
  elsif next_move == "take key" and chest_open
    key_present = true      
  puts "You take the key and slip it into a pocket."
    puts "What do you do?"
    prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
  elsif next_move == "go back"
    start()
  else puts "I don't understand you."
    puts "What do you do?"
    prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
    end
  end
end  

def start
  puts "You find yourself in a dank room lit by torches."
  puts "There are three doors leading out of here."
puts "What do you do?"
door_open = false
key_present = false
while true
  prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
  if next_move == "door 1"
    chest_room()
  elsif next_move == "door 2"
    dais()
  elsif next_move == "door 3" and not door_open
    puts "This door is securely locked."
    puts "You'll need to find some way of opening it before you can enter."
    puts "What do you do?"
    prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
  elsif next_move == "door 3" and key_present
    door_open = true
    puts "The key you found fits easily into the lock."
    puts "With a click, you unlock the door!"
    orb_room()
  else 
    puts "I don't understand you."
    puts "What do you do?"
    prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
    end
  end
end
```

Any input or advice? Essentially, I want to end the door_open = false loop once the key is found, but I can't figure out how to set door_open = true in the chest_room method then call it from the start method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having scope issues. make the door_open or key_present instance variables by putting an @ in front of them. Then any method can access them. also case/when is cleaner than if elsif

```
while !@key_present # @key_present can be modified in another method
  prompt; next_move = gets.chomp
  case
    when "door 1" == next_move then chest_room() # put constants first when comparing ==
    when "door 2" == next_move then dais()
    # more conditions
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like your solution better than what I've been doing up until now, so I'll try this out.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is to back up and think out the design again.  You have a Room, and it has a property "open" or "closed".  You have a Key, and you need the key to change the state of that open/closed property.

Write out what you want to do, and think about how to model it as a Room and a Key, and you'll be on a better track.

(No, I don't want to give you the answer.  Figuring it out is more important.)

Comment: +1 If you don't follow this advice, your code is likely going end up being very complicated, resembling http://bit.ly/o37l86

Comment: I definitely need to remember that link.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Thanks for the input! I've been following along with Learn Ruby the Hard Way to build up my Ruby skills and probably got too myopic thinking about this problem. I'll rethink what I'm doing per your advice and give it another shot.